# What's the best HTML5 element to use for a parenthetical?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, parentheses

I've been looking for an HTML5 element to mark text in parentheses. My first instinct is to use the `<ASIDE>` element, but [the HTML5 definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element) for this explicitly says:

> **Note:** It's not appropriate to use the aside element just for parentheticals, since those are part of the main flow of the document.

**What, then, should be used for parentheticals?**

### Implementation

---

Below is what I ended up using. Thanks to unor for pointing out that `<SMALL>` is defined to represent "side comments", which, IMO, includes parentheticals.

CSS:

```
SMALL.parenthetical {
    font-size: inherit;
}
    SMALL.parenthetical:before {
        content: "(";
    }
    SMALL.parenthetical:after {
        content: ")";
    }
```

HTML:

```
<P>Today I wrote some code <SMALL CLASS="parenthetical">In CSS and HTML</SMALL> that helped me out greatly</P>
```

Comment: As an `<aside>`, as someone who doesn't do much with semantic markup: why would you want to use anything other than standard parentheses for parentheticals? Seems like it's a small step from that, to looking for markup for sentence clauses, tenses... Strictly out of curiosity, what's your use case?

Comment: SEO, as our search engine can more easily recognize parentheticals this way. Translation, as non-english languages use brackets other than rounded parentheses (like 【 and 】 in Japanese). Style, as, in the future, we may decide that [ and ] or ⟨ and ⟩ look better on the page than ( and ).
In short, same reason you would use `<Q></Q>` and not `""`

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: It's nice to be able to exclude parentheticals from excerpts, eg. Wikipedia article introductions, which frequently contain translations, pronunciations, birth dates, etc. before the opening sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific element for parentheses.

In *some* cases the [`small` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element) might be appropriate.

You have to use the punctuation marks (e.g., the round brackets `(` and `)`) *explicitly* as part of the HTML (so *not* included via CSS `content`).

If you want to be able to style the whole parenthesis resp. the brackets, you should use `span` elements, as they don’t have any meaning. For example:

```
<p>At vero eos duo <span class="parenthesis">(consetetur sadipscing elitr)</span> dolores et ea rebum.</p> 

<p>At vero eos duo <span class="parenthesis-start">(</span>consetetur sadipscing elitr<span class="parenthesis-end">)</span> dolores et ea rebum.</p>
```

Now you *could* visually hide the brackets and add other punctuation marks (or similar) via CSS’s `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements.

Comment: Please elaborate; why do I "have to use" parentheses explicitly?

Comment: @Supuhstar: Because there is no specific element (similar to `q`), we can’t rely on user-agents providing the punctuation. CSS-only addition of punctuation (via `content` and pseudo-element) doesn’t change the meaning of the document, only its decoration; for e.g. text browser or screen reader users there wouldn’t be any way to differentiate the parenthesis from the surrounding text.

Comment: @unor HTML's `<ruby>` supports parenthesis annotations with `<rp>`: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/rp

Answer (score -2):

[This](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) has exactly what you are looking for if I am not wrong.

Comment: Those are just the characters characters; I'm looking for the DOM elements (or, more specifically, the tags that represent them) that best represent parentheses. That said, it's a useful page, and I'll bookmark it.